# Best reply to "Have a nice weekend"?

Tags: conversation

Someone says: "Have a nice weekend!"

Which of these replies suits best? Consider saying this to a foreign person, not a friend:

- "Same to you."
- "You too."
- "I wish you, too."

Feel free to post if there's an even better answer.

Comment: what has your research shown?

Comment: “Thanks, you too” is what I generally use, polite enough to use on anyone.

Comment: What do you do if they sent a substantive email and then signed off with "Have a great weekend!" and, in your response, you need to address one of those substantive points and _then_ sign off? In that case, how do you refer back to the whole weekend discussion in a natural way?

Comment: Hi @Jacob are you asking a question that you want answers to? If so, you should use the question function to ask it. Right now your question is buried in the comment section and may be seen by few people. Plus, comments often get deleted or moved. If you are asking for clarification to *this*, then that's fine. It just seems like you are asking an actual question, not seeking clarification.

Comment: Grimace because of the awful expression with it’s use of the weak “nice”?

Comment: @David I think so too, I feel it would be better if it was "good"

Answer (score 1):

"I wish you, too" sounds a bit strange to me as a AmE, "Same to you" is not super natural. I would prefer "You too!".

You could also add a "thanks" in front or behind this, e.g.

> thanks, you too!

*this is also mentioned by @JonLarby in the comments*

I do also see that "have a nice weekend" sounds awkward, might be better if "good" is used.